# CakePHP Paginaton: How to get pagination for comments when I'm using pagination for posts

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, cakephp

I have a Post Model and a comment Model. The association between Post Model and Cake Model is as follow

```
 Post has many comments
 Comments belongs to Post
```

I'm using pagination to implement the "infinite scroll" thing on my page.

```
    public $paginate = array('limit' => 15,
        'order' => array('Post.id' => 'desc'),'conditions' => array('Post.hidden' => 0)
    );
```

and

```
        $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
        $post = $this->Paginator->paginate('Post');
        $this->set('posts',$post);
```

but that retrieves all the comments associated with a post. I want pagination for Comments too. Is there any way I can implement it in cakephp? I want to show only 3 comments and "view more comments" link, just like we have it on Facebook.

I know I can easily implement that feature by initially fetching all the comments from the database but showing only last three comments and then by using ajax  to fetch another three and so on. But I'm looking for a better and easier way.

Comment: if it is a separate thing (comments vs posts sounds like it), then all you need is a 2nd AJAX request to a 2nd action "get_comments" etc.

Comment: Edit your question and show your UI so I will be able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend splitting the retrieval of posts and associated comments rather than rely on CakePHP's model engine so that the logic for managing comments is consolidated to as few areas of your code as possible (as first suggested by mark in comments). In other words, render the post first and then fire off an AJAX request for the first page of comments.

In the AJAX request, you need to communicate both the post id and page you want to retrieve the comments for. For instance, assuming your request is in the format of `SomeController/comments/[postId]/[commentsPage]`

In your controller you would have an action that was laid out like the following:

```
public function comments($postId, $page) {
    ...
}
```

You're also going to need to tweak the `Paginator` settings so it can include comments. Lay it out a bit like this (of course add your own detail for the `Comment` section):

```
public $paginate = array(
    'Post' => array('limit' => 15, 'order' => array('Post.id' => 'desc'),'conditions' => array('Post.hidden' => 0)),
    'Comment' => array(...)
);
```

Inside your comments action, you need to supply additional conditions and page number to the `Paginator`:

```
// tweak the paginator settings for the Comments model
$this->paginate['Comments']['page'] = $page;
$this->paginate['Comments']['conditions'] = array('Comments.postId', $postId);
// get some comments
$comments = $this->Paginator->paginate('Comments');
$this->set('comments', $comments);
```

Of course you're going to have to write some JavaScript to make the AJAX requests and keep track of the comments page you're on. This is the client's responsibility to manage all of this, not the server's (your CakePHP application). Don't make it do too much!